# notify RecyclerView adapter from fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

i have a RecyclerView with Dialog Fragment , and i get data from user in via the Dialog and stored it in the database then , i display it in recyclerview , and all this is working , my problem is , when i add the data i must restart the app to display it into recycler , how i can notify the adapter data is change ?

the add button in the Dialog Fragment

```
  add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);

 private void insert() {
        Title = addTitle.getText().toString();
        Des= addDesc.getText().toString();
        db.insertIntoDB(Title, Des);}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (addTitle.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
            addTitle.setError(" Title is required!");
        } else if (addDesc.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
            addDesc.setError(" Postion is required!");
        }

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"your data is saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        insert();
    }
```

and this is the getdata method in the helper class

```
public List<ToDoModule> getDataFromDB(){
    List<ToDoModule> modelList = new ArrayList<ToDoModule>();
    String query = "select * from "+ TODO_TABLE;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {

            ToDoModule model = new ToDoModule();
            model.setActionTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            model.setActionDesc(cursor.getString(2));
            modelList.add(model);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return modelList;
}
```

and this is the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public List<ToDoModule> dbList;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
DatabaseHelpher helpher;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    helpher = new DatabaseHelpher(this);
    dbList= new ArrayList<ToDoModule>();
    dbList = helpher.getDataFromDB();
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.AppRecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this,dbList);
    this.dbList =helpher.getDataFromDB();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_name);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            addAction add = new addAction();
            add.show(fm,"fragment_edit_name");
        }});}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DialogFragments, like all fragments, are directly tied to the lifecycle of the Activity that uses them. Therefore the onResume() callback is not called by the activity after a user dismisses the dialogFragment.

For simplicity and easy maintainability, I would create an **interface**,

```
public interface DialogFragUpdateListener {
    public void OnDBUpdate();
}
```

which your activity will **implement**,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  DialogFragUpdateListener{
```

that receives a **callback** whenever the user finishes the action you are having them do in the DialogFragment. I would add this in your **onClick()** method after the **insert()** is called:

```
(DialogFragUpdateListener)getActivity()).OnDBUpdate()
```

Then in your activity, this callback method can them query the updated data from the database and update the adapter/recyclerview again:

```
 public void OnDBUpdate() {
        // Requery data from database here
     getDataFromDB();
    }
```

Check this out for reference:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity